# jQuery plugin getting overwritten by another implementation of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I'm working on a Chrome extension that injects some scripts into Gmail, like jQuery and [qtip](http://qtip2.com/). It worked without any problem until I added the Chrome extension [LinkedIn Sales Navigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkedin-sales-navigator/eekjikilggkdpjklgpnceahcioemadje/), which (I checked) is using jQuery too.

After adding it, I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).qtip is not a function(…)

And `console.log($.qtip)` returns `undefined`, while before adding this extension it was returning the function.

My flow to inject these scripts is:

- In the manifest's `"content_scripts"` section I'm adding `content.js`.
- In `content.js` file I'm using `document.createElement("script")` for each script and append it to the page's `<head>`.

I don't know what the problem is but I think it's an overwrite issue with jQuery but I'm not sure why nor how to solve it.

Thanks ahead for any help !

Comment: That extension injects jQuery v2.1.1 into the page, so you'll have to use jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for that, I didn't knew it existed. If I understand well the docs about it, it gives the ability to get jquery back to the first invoked version (or to Jquery when the conflict is with another library). With this case it will work, I guess. But I can't know which version will be loaded first all the time. Should I test `$.qtip` to see if I should invoke `noConflict` ?

Comment: The word `version` simply means `instance`. The documentation is slightly ambiguous.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, testing `$.qtip` is apparently the way to go for my use case (because if I was just invoking `jQuery.noConflict();` anyway, when removing the other extension, I had a `$ is undefined` error). If you think it's ok to do as I did feel free to post an answer I could accept.

Comment: The thing is, I don't use jQuery, I just know the bits and pieces, so it's better if you write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to the comments I found out `jQuery.noConflict();` existed, and have been able to check the availability of the wanted function and act accordingly :

```
if(!$.qtip)
    jQuery.noConflict();
```